# How to reduce footer view of a list view

Tags: android, list, height, footer

I have a list and I am adding a footer view to it. But the height of the footer view is always fixed. I want something of around half of its size but footer view's size not at all changing. I tried with many combinations in its xml layout file. Please help.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ff0000" 
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Footer...." />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u need to set height of that inflating footerview Layout

Comment: What is the view that you are using as a footer? Some code would be nice...

Comment: I tried setting height but its not working.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff0000" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer...." />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: put your code in your answer as an Edit!it's not readable

Answer (score 2):

finally the following worked.......... :P :P

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_bottom_indent" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add FooterView inside the list at runtime and Chnage It's LayoutParams Accordingly

```
    Button addButton = new Button(this);
    addButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lv.addFooterView(addButton, null, true);
```

OR

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, container, false);
    View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_category, null);
     LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, getResources.getDimension(R.dimen.height));
     footerView.setLayoutParams(lp)
    listview.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: I have some layout instead of button.. but even params are not working :(

Comment: @SP Code Edited, try to Inflate the code at runtime set it's width, height Accordinigly.

Comment: @strike : there is no need to change params at runtime,changing Xml should work.